# In Sails.js is it possible to just add validation to automatically generated rest api's?

Tags: mysql, sails.js

New to sails.js and was using the auto generated default api's
but then I want to know if I could add just a little customization
to it without having to rewrite the whole code for it again.

at the moment, i wanted to customize the /create api and so wrote this code

```
create:function(req,res){
       var username = req.query.username;
       var password = req.query.password;
       if(password==='faraz'){
           res.send('cant set password to faraz');
       }else if(!password){
           res.send('cant set blank password');
       }else{
       TestAPI.create(req.query).exec(function(err,newUser){
           if(err){
               res.send(err);
           }
           var username = newUser.username;
           var createdUser = {username:username};
           res.send(createdUser);
       });
       }

    }
```

now, in the above code I have written the full code here, with the validation and then using the create api myself. so, the automatically generated api was not very useful here as I had to write everything myself. so, what exactly is the use of these shortcut api's if i still need to write the whole thing to just add validation.

or maybe I am missing something. in that case, tell me how you would add validation to the /create without having to write the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you haven't specified which sails version you use, but for the v1.0 here how it is done in the model: https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?custom-validation-rules
So you can avoid doing checks in the controller and catch the error of creating the record (if any).